# Bottleneck in Azure App Service on wake up

Tags: api, azure, .net-core

I have Developed an API using .NET Core, Swagger, MySQL and Azure App Services.

When I first "wake up" the application in the morning it sometimes takes 43000ms to get a response back! Each subsequent call is between 500ms & 2500ms which is pretty reasonable.

Which part of my stack is taking the longest to wake up? The App Service, the MySql database or the API code itself? How can I diagnose this in Azure to determine the speeds and bottlenecks?

Comment: Without seeing or knowing any details from your app, it's impossible to know what part of your app is taking the longest to get started. But... you should probably look at the "always on" option to make sure your service is warmed up properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David mentioned, you can enable "Always On" from settings:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure

Another thing, you can try remote profiling your app. It will help you to understand what's the bottleneck.

https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/remote-profiling-support-in-azure-app-service/

*P.S. Also I believe 500ms/2500ms is still too much for an API. I don't know what your service does tho*

Comment: I have it below 100 ms now but still inconsistent on shared dev instance